# Adding two integers of a double digit integer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer

I was attempting a coding practice where I had to take a two digit integer, split the integer into its two digits and add those digits.

```
function addTwoDigits(n) {
var n = n
var string = n.toString()
var split = string.split("")
var integer= split.map(Number)
var z = integer[0]+integer[1]
console.log(z)

}
```

The output of my code was correct on each of the tests, but the code checks still failed. If anyone can provide some insight into why, I would appreciate it.

Comment: How does the code check checks your code? Does it specify a specific type that your answer needs to be in?

Comment: What is the point of `var n = n` ?

Comment: You could do that in a single line
`function addTwoDigits(n) {return Math.floor(n/10) + (n%10));}`

Comment: @CedricCholley Thank you that worked great, I definitely will have to look more into Math.floor

Comment: @AvivLo it checks my code against random double digit integers and sees if the output of my code matches the correct answers or expected output based on those values

Comment: @JackDempsey I'll make an official answer then

Answer (score 2):

You could write the function this way

```
function addTwoDigits(n) {
    return Math.floor(n/10) + (n%10));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue before. The solution for me was returning the value, rather than logging it to the console.

Instead of `console.log(z)` try `return z`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "but the code checks still failed". Here's a oneliner for n-digit numbers, using a [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const sumOfIndividualDigits = n => 
  [...`${n}`]
  // ^ convert to Array of strings
  .map(Number)
  //   ^convert element (back) to Numbers
  .reduce( (acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
  //       ^ reduce to 1 value (sum)
  
console.log(sumOfIndividualDigits(22));
console.log(sumOfIndividualDigits(12345678));
```